# universal and existential quantifier in prolog

Tags: prolog, universal, existential-type, quantifiers

How can I implement following rules in prolog.

I write the “ No spiders are mammals” sentence as Existential and universal:

```
¬∃x(mammals(X) ∧ spider(X) ) //It is not the case that mammals are spider

∀X(mammals(X) ⇒ ¬spider(X)) //All mammals are non-spider.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have a database with the following facts:

```
mammals(cat).
mammals(dog).
 ...

spider(blackwidow).
 ...
```

Now you can issue a rewrite your sentence into a prolog query quite straightforward:

¬∃x(mammals(X) ∧ spider(X) ) //It is not the case that mammals are spider

```
?- \+((mammals(X), spider(X))).
true.
```

and

∀X(mammals(X) ⇒ ¬spider(X)) //All mammals are non-spider.

```
?- forall(mammals(X), \+spider(X)).
true.
```

Comment: Is there a way to I implement these rules in 'x.pl' Environment ? I mean add the rules to the database?

Comment: You can add a procedure which succeeds when the condition holds, just add the query onto the body of a procedure. E.g.: `no_mammal_is_spider:-  \+((mammals(X), spider(X))).`

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Could you please guide me how can I add following sentence in prolog as a rule? ∀X(q(X) OR b(X) ⇒ Mammal(X)) %All mammal are either ‘q’ OR ‘B’. I wrote it but I don’t know what’s the problem: `C(cat).` `Mammal (X) :- forall(q(X) V b(X))` Finally I should answer this question: Is ‘cat’ is a mammal? `?-mammal(cat)`

Comment: %All mammal are either ‘q’ OR ‘b’ would be written `forall(mammals(X), ( q(X) ; b(X) ) ).`

Comment: `mammal(b).`  `mammal(q).` `forall(mammal(X), ( q(X) ; b(X) ) ).` `q(cat).` `cat(pishi).`
Then I write `?- mammal(pishi)` But I get `false`. Instead of `true`.

Comment: I think you are getting this wrong. `mammal(pishi)` gets `false` because your program states that there are only two mammals, b and q, with b and q being atoms. The forall(...) written in the program would be a fact, not what you intended.